# Extracting the filename (excluding file extension)

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to just get the file name (excluding the .png or .jpg) for my script.  It should be simple string manipulation, but I'm really not strong with that in Google Apps Script.

```
data = [

                file.getName(), <---- I need to know how to get 123456
                file.getName(), <---- if this is 123456.jpg
                file.getDateCreated(),
                "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + file.getId(),
            ];

            alldata.push(data);
```

So my extraction data looks like this, how can I get it without the .jpg (or .png or .whatever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Logger.log("123456.jpg".slice(0,"123456.jpg".indexOf(".")));//123456
```

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var filename=file.getName();
var filenameWithoutExt=filename.slice(0,filename.lastIndexOf(.));
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks spot on.  (Just fix the (.) to (".").

Comment: You would prefer to use lastIndexOf(".") in case the file name contains a dot ... this would get the actual last dot in the string.

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thanks for pointing that out.  That's something I'll  want to remember.